# Real number of text occurrences in SQLITE FTS Match

Tags: android, database, sqlite, search, full-text-search

I am using SQLite FTS to find text in text articles:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM enrondata1 WHERE content MATCH 'linux';
```

This will return number of articles containing **linux**, but not number of times linux found in each of articles.
But I also need real number of times **linux** found, not just number of articles.
For example I may have 2 articles contaning linux, but found 10 times in each of articles, so there is actually 20 **linux** words.
How can I find this count, which is 20?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [offsets() function](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#the_offsets_function) returns information about each match. However, you cannot simply `count()` the results; you have to aggregate them yourself.